# Why is there no progress bar in dlply (in the R plyr package)

Tags: r, progress-bar, plyr

I am using the plyr package to process lists and data frames.
I have noticed the following behaviour:

Example 1 -

```
list_2 <- llply(list_1, function_1, .progress='text')
```

this works as expected. It generates list_2 from list_1 with function_1 applied to each list_1 element and I see the progress bar.

Example 2 -

```
list_3 <- dlply(list_2, function_2, .progress='text')
```

this also works insofar as I get the results in list_3 that I expect, however,  I do not get a progress bar.

In summary, why does the progress bar not work for dlply but works for llply. (It also works for ldply).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're not splitting your `data.frame` on anything. If your second example was:

```
list_3 <- dlply(df_2, .(colname2), function_2, .progress='text')
```

then it would work. The progress meter in plyr is based on the number of chunks completed.